# Indentation on items

Tags: indentation, itemize

I do I indent the "Output" item label, the same as the "Input" item label in the following code while keeping all other indentation the same as now:

```
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{3cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item[Input:] bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
\item[Output:] bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
\end{itemize}
\end{adjustwidth}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
```

[image]

Here is what I want to have:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. It's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from. For your question the answer depends on the document class that you are using and any packages that you load which affect the `enumerate` environment.

Comment: (i) `itemize` is not intended for what you doing. use `description` instead (ii) please provide complete, self contained small document, which we can test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is: load  `enumitem`, if not already done, and use the `[align=left]` option (default is `[align=right]`):

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{changepage, enumitem}

    \begin{document}

bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{3cm}
\begin{itemize}[align = left]
\item[Input:] bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\item[Output:] bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\end{itemize}
\end{adjustwidth}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

enter image description here
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @TamarEV: As mentioned by Zarko, why don't you  use the `description  environment?

Comment: I asked a follow-up question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393715/using-package-enumitem-with-my-header-causes-enumerate-list-to-not-compile maybe you can take a look...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `[Input:]` declaration, and replace it by simply `\item Input:` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\begin{itemize}
\item Input: bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\item Output: bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\end{itemize}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

If you would not like the bullets, use:

```
\item[] Input: bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\item[] Output: bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
```

Both approaches will give you the desired output

Comment: Still not it... I wish for the "Input:" and "Output:" to stand out from the rest of the sentence