# Using package enumitem with my header causes enumerate list to not compile

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, incompatibility

I am trying to implement to solution to this problem [Indentation on items](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393638/indentation-on-items#393641)
but something is not working together with my header.

This compiles and looks like I want it to, but doesn't have the enumerated list:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=3.2cm,  includefoot,  footskip=30pt,]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage, enumitem}
%\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for images
\usepackage{color,soul} % for highlights
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %for links
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{enumerate}

% for equation caption
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionType{mycapequ}[][List of equations]
\captionsetup[mycapequ]{labelformat=empty}

\oddsidemargin=0.15in
\evensidemargin=0.15in
\topmargin=-.5in
\textheight=9in
\textwidth=6.25in

\usepackage{refcount}

\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2\textwidth}\rlap{#1}}
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{{\color{red}\bf TODO: #1}}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\newcolumntype{K}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}


bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{3cm}
\begin{itemize}[align = left]
\item[Input:]  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
\item[Output:]  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
\end{itemize}
\end{adjustwidth}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 


%\begin{enumerate}
%\item bla bla bla bla
%\item bla bla bla bla
%\item bla bla bla bla
%\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This compiles and has the enumerated list but doesn't look like I want it to:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=3.2cm,  includefoot,  footskip=30pt,]{geometry}
%\usepackage{changepage, enumitem}
\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for images
\usepackage{color,soul} % for highlights
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %for links
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{enumerate}

% for equation caption
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionType{mycapequ}[][List of equations]
\captionsetup[mycapequ]{labelformat=empty}

\oddsidemargin=0.15in
\evensidemargin=0.15in
\topmargin=-.5in
\textheight=9in
\textwidth=6.25in

\usepackage{refcount}

\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2\textwidth}\rlap{#1}}
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{{\color{red}\bf TODO: #1}}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\newcolumntype{K}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}


bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{3cm}
\begin{itemize}%[align = left]
\item[Input:]  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
\item[Output:]  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
\end{itemize}
\end{adjustwidth}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 


\begin{enumerate}
\item bla bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla bla
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This doesn't compile:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=3.2cm,  includefoot,  footskip=30pt,]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage, enumitem}
%\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for images
\usepackage{color,soul} % for highlights
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %for links
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{enumerate}

% for equation caption
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionType{mycapequ}[][List of equations]
\captionsetup[mycapequ]{labelformat=empty}

\oddsidemargin=0.15in
\evensidemargin=0.15in
\topmargin=-.5in
\textheight=9in
\textwidth=6.25in

\usepackage{refcount}

\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2\textwidth}\rlap{#1}}
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{{\color{red}\bf TODO: #1}}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\newcolumntype{K}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}


bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{3cm}
\begin{itemize}[align = left]
\item[Input:]  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
\item[Output:]  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
\end{itemize}
\end{adjustwidth}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 


\begin{enumerate}
\item bla bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla bla
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

And this is the error message I get:

```
! Undefined control sequence.\enit@endenumerate ->\enit@after\endlist \ifx \enit@series \relax \else \if... \end{enumerate}
```

What is going on?

Comment: You load the geometry package but then use these low level assignments and undo all the settings it made? `\oddsidemargin=0.15in
\evensidemargin=0.15in
\topmargin=-.5in
\textheight=9in
\textwidth=6.25in`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your compilation problem is due to loading both `enumerate` and `enumitem` which conflict together.

I cleaned and simplified your code, removed any package loading which has nothing to do with your problem. In particular, I think you don't need the `adjustwidth` environment here, as `enumitem` provides the same functionality for list environments. Furthermore, the `description` environment is more appropriate for the first list than `itemize`.

So hopefully, the following code gives the layout you want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=3.2cm, width=6.25in, height=9in, hmargin =1.15in, includefoot, footskip=30pt,]{geometry}
\usepackage{ enumitem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

\begin{description}[font=\normalfont, labelindent=1cm, nosep, leftmargin=1.5cm, rightmargin=3cm]%
  \item[Input:] bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  \item[Output:] bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\end{description}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

\begin{enumerate}[wide=1cm, leftmargin=*]
  \item bla bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla bla
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can not use `enumitem` and `enumerate` packages at the same time, and there is no point as `enumitem` has all the features of `enumerate` plus additional ones. Your final example works without error if you remove

```
\usepackage{enumerate}
```